# Erro ao verificar radio com if

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação simples de if e else, porém não estou conseguindo, pois ele só retorna como true quando na verdade no caso que estou tentar testar era para retornar false.

Segue como estou tentando:

```
function FinalizarCompra(){
  var ainput = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard.checked;
  var ainput2 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard2.checked;
  var ainput3 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard3.checked;
  var ainput4 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard4.checked;
  var ainput5 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard5.checked;
  if(ainput5 == false){
    alert('Por favor, selecione o Tipo de Endereço.');
    alert(ainput5);
  }else{
    alert('funciono');
    alert(ainput5);
  }
}
```

Estou chamando essa função por um click de um button que esta fora do  isso poderia ser o que esta ocasionando isso?

HTML da parte do radio

```
<div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1 cc-selector">
    <p><strong>ESCOLHA O MODELO DE SUA CAIXA</strong></p>  
        <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4A">
          <input id="Caixa Basica" alt="Caixa Basica" title="Caixa Basica" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="20" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
          <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaBasica" alt="Caixa Basica" title="Caixa Basica" for="Caixa Basica"></label>
          <span>Básica</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4B">
          <input id="Caixa Premium" alt="Caixa Premium" title="Caixa Premium" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="40" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
          <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaPremium" alt="Caixa Premium" title="Caixa Premium" for="Caixa Premium"></label>
          <span>Premium</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4C">
          <input id="Caixa Cesta" alt="Caixa Cesta" title="Caixa Cesta" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="50" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
          <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaCesta" alt="Caixa Cesta" title="Caixa Cesta" for="Caixa Cesta"></label>
          <span>Cesta</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4D">
          <input id="Caixa 50 Tons" alt="Caixa 50 Tons" title="Caixa 50 Tons" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="160" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
          <label class="drinkcard-cc caixa50Tons" alt="Caixa 50 Tons" title="Caixa 50 Tons" for="Caixa 50 Tons"></label>
          <span>50 Tons</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Não é o completo, pois ficaria muito extenso, mas os outros blocos praticamente são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Jovem, adiciona o HTML e faz um [mcve]. Assim qualquer um pode tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Nesse teste que realizei usando essa variavel - alert(ainput5); - esta retornando isso: undefined

Comment: Ok, segue como está o html

Comment: Já inclui o html, se puder dar uma olhada agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você deve fazer é verificar se o `radio` retorna um valor, e não se está checado, pois eles são vários.

Faça desta forma para validar, trocando o `checked` por `value`:

```js
function FinalizarCompra(){
  var ainput = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard.value;
//  var ainput2 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard2.checked;
//  var ainput3 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard3.checked;
//  var ainput4 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard4.checked;
//  var ainput5 = document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard5.checked;
  if(ainput == false){
    alert('Por favor, selecione o Tipo de Endereço.');
    alert(ainput);
  }else{
    alert('funciono');
    alert(ainput);
  }
}

// só para não dar erro
function calcularPrimeiro(){}
```

```html
<form name="formMonteCaixa">
<div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1 cc-selector">
    <p><strong>ESCOLHA O MODELO DE SUA CAIXA</strong></p>  
  <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4A">
    <input id="Caixa Basica" alt="Caixa Basica" title="Caixa Basica" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="20" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaBasica" alt="Caixa Basica" title="Caixa Basica" for="Caixa Basica"></label>
    <span>Básica</span>
  </div>
  <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4B">
    <input id="Caixa Premium" alt="Caixa Premium" title="Caixa Premium" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="40" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaPremium" alt="Caixa Premium" title="Caixa Premium" for="Caixa Premium"></label>
    <span>Premium</span>
  </div>
  <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4C">
    <input id="Caixa Cesta" alt="Caixa Cesta" title="Caixa Cesta" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="50" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc caixaCesta" alt="Caixa Cesta" title="Caixa Cesta" for="Caixa Cesta"></label>
    <span>Cesta</span>
  </div>
  <div class="ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4 ModeloCaixaBloco1Col4D">
    <input id="Caixa 50 Tons" alt="Caixa 50 Tons" title="Caixa 50 Tons" type="radio" name="creditCard" value="160" onclick="calcularPrimeiro()" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc caixa50Tons" alt="Caixa 50 Tons" title="Caixa 50 Tons" for="Caixa 50 Tons"></label>
    <span>50 Tons</span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<button onclick="FinalizarCompra()">Finalizar compra</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado dessa forma funcionou, só uma duvida não estava funcionando por que estava retornando um array entre os outros radios do mesmo name? ou não? Cara e se não for pedir de mais tenho outro problema dentro dessa mesma função.

Comment: if(ainput5 == false){
    alert('Para finalizar a compra é necessario informar a quantidade de salgados.');
    document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard5.focus();
  }else{
    alert('funciono');
    alert(ainput5);
  }

Comment: Entrou tentando utilizar o focus para que o usuário entenda onde está o erro, porém ele não está funcionando e retorna um erro no console do Ghrome: Uncaught TypeError: document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard5.focus is not a function
    at FinalizarCompra ((index):262)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):566)

Comment: Coloque assim: `document.formMonteCaixa.creditCard[0].focus();`

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado !